# Deploying Azure VM to port 8081 not working

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have created a classic VM on Microsoft Azure. I have deployed a .Net Web Application using IIS web server. I have added the ports 80, 8080, 8081 under HTTP/TCP endpoint and 443 and 44300 under HTTPS/TCP endpoint. 
[Snapshot of end points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4zUE.png)

If I bind my application on ports 80, 8080 or 443, I am able to access it from outside the VM, that is my personal computer. However, the ports 8081 and 44300 are not accessible from outside.

For these ports I am able to access the website using 
http:// localhost:8080 and https:// localhost:44300. If I try http:// {domain_name}:8080 and https:// {domain_name}:44300, the browser is unable to connect to the server.

All the endpoints have been added in the same way.

Is it because of a firewall issue? Am I missing something here?

Comment: this belongs on ServerFault, not StackOverflow. When you repost, you should include a screenshot of your endpoint setup.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely need to add entries for the non-standard ports in the Windows Firewall with Advanced Security.

Excerpt from https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-set-up-endpoints/

> NOTE: : Firewall configuration for Azure virtual machines is done
>   automatically for ports associated with Remote Desktop and Secure
>   Shell (SSH), and in most cases for Windows PowerShell Remoting. For
>   ports specified for all other endpoints, no configuration is done
>   automatically to the firewall of the virtual machine. When you create
>   an endpoint for the virtual machine, you'll need to ensure that the
>   firewall of the virtual machine also allows the traffic for the
>   protocol and private port corresponding to the endpoint configuration.

Comment: the article linked is about classic virtual machines, do you know any resource about new VMs?

Comment: The link was included as a source for the NOTE. The NOTE section applies to both Classic VMs and Resource Manager VMs. Microsoft has done this because of security. If you're looking for how to set up endpoints in the portal for new VMs, that a different question. Microsoft's documentation at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/virtual-machines/ has a lot of information. You should look at Endpoint ACLs and Network Security Groups.